# How to install an NTP-server that is vulnerable to NTP-amplification

Tags: debian, ntp

I'm trying to install an NTP-server that is vulnerable to NTP-amplification for a demo. I'm using this script to perform the demo: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/37562/
But I can't find any vulnerable server.

**Where can I find NTP-server software that is vulnerable to NTP-amplification?**

*I'm using ubuntu server 15.04*

edit:

disabled ufw

changed /etc/conf file te be http://pastebin.com/sSX7zdyg

Comment: The amplification attacks work because they do not talk to only one server, but to several. A "vulnerable" server is simply one that has no restriction on the clients it serves. Obviously as most of the ntp software out there come nowadays by default locked (to localhost), it has became harder to find "open" ntp servers. However they are still out there. I would recommend first and foremost to understand the actions and the underlying architecture of what you are trying to accomplish. I also review  the code *always* when downloading exploit scripts.

Comment: Yes I understand the exploit that I am running. I am only trying to prove that you can use an ntp-server to attack another host. I am not actually trying to take down a host. I am executing the script but I don't see any incoming traffic on my "target host" when using ifstat -S. 
Should a change a setting on my ntp server?

Comment: Even with the right setup, it all depends in the firewall rules of the ntp server and the network where it is located also. They can have rules against spoofing. Have a look at https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2014/01/21/how-qualysguard-detects-vulnerability-to-ntp-amplification-attacks last paragraphs.

Comment: It's my own vm, I disabled ufw to be sure it doesn't interfere.
in /etc/ntp/conf do I just comment the two lines?

Comment: coud you post it here?

Comment: I edited my post, included a pastebin link that contains my config file

Comment: take out all the lines that start by restrict, the four of them.

Comment: commented the 4 lines, restarted ntp service....didn't show any results
HOWEVER: I rebooted my VM's and now IT WORKS YEEEY.
Thanks you very much!
If you're ever in Belgium I'll buy you a beer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32347/discussion-between-jelle-criel-and-rui-f-ribeiro).

Comment: No ideia why you did not have to reboot, odd. Maybe restart did not do a proper kill, only checking the init scripts. Glad it is working now. I will write a post for the benefit of others. BTW, I welcome point, but much more new linked.in connections.

Comment: restart does a 2 second sleep in Debian. Other than that, is it a full stop and start, should had worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amplification attacks work because bad actors do talk to several vulnerable servers at once. A "vulnerable" server is simply one that has no restriction on the clients it serves and/or other vulnerabilities that can be exploited. Obviously as most of the ntp software out there come nowadays by default locked (to localhost), it has became harder to find "open" ntp servers. However they are still out there. I also review the code *always* when downloading exploit scripts.

That said, to fully open your ntpd server for testing, you comment out the restrict directives present in /etc/ntpd.conf

```
#restrict -4 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer
#restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
#restrict 127.0.0.1
#restrict ::1
```

Then do:

```
sudo service ntp restart
```

Be aware that this is for testing out, and should be in a network that has no communications to the outside. Keep only it active during the tests.

Here is a link about the theme:

https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2014/01/21/how-qualysguard-detects-vulnerability-to-ntp-amplification-attacks